# С чего начать изучение программирования?

Tags: java, книги

Я решил выбрать программирование своей будущей профессией. Сейчас хочу разобраться в основах программирования. Скажите, с чего лучше начать и какие пособия лучше использовать? Сейчас я нашел неплохой учебник по Java, но я не знаю, является ли оно лучшим вариантом.

Comment: Посмотрите похожий вопрос - http://hashcode.ru/questions/5051/

Comment: 10 лет работаю программистом, ОДУМАЙСЯ :)

Comment: Закройте уже этот вопрос! Опять холиварить начали. Здесь к Хэшкоду предложение напрашивается: сделать на сайте голосования.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С Java дела обстоят так же, как и со многими другими. Всё как обычно: читаете книжку или даже статью о том, как вообще пишутся элементарные вещи типа Hello World, осваиваете простые вещи, такие как циклы, ветвления, классы и т.п. Как и обычно, после этого нужна практика: ставите себе цели - решаете, ставите новые - опять решаете.

> Сейчас я нашел неплохой учебник по Java, но я не знаю, является ли оно лучшим вариантом

Мера того, насколько хорош учебник, - то, насколько вам понятно, что там написано. И, разумеется, учебник не должен никогда вводить в заблуждение (не должно быть заведомо ложных сведений), но это бывает редко. Если вам всё ясно, значит учебник годится, по крайней мере, для начала.

Из классики по сабжу:

- [Thinking in Java](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3191205/) она же [Философия Java](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4073388/)
- [Паттерны проектирования Гаммы, Хельма и др.](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/)
- [Java. Эффективное программирование](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1259354/)
- [Горький вкус Java](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1425895/)

Многие рекомендуют Шилдта, но, по мне, это не лучший выбор. Есть прецеденты введения им в заблуждение. К тому же, этот человек пытается быть экспертом **ПО ВСЕМУ**. У него и C#, и плюсы, ява. Это наверняка указывает на ограниченность опыта в каждом из направлений, в котором он "вещает".

**UPD**

Я забыл указать главное. Прежде чем что-то вообще читать надо привести в порядок голову и добиться ясности в ней.

Comment: П. Грэм. Обложка Джавы. http://www.paulgraham.com/javacover.html Правда, уже староватая и на английском. Но автор известный (в прошлом - пионер в создании веб-приложений) :))) Программирование сделало его миллионером, сейчас бизнесмен в области ИТ. У него там много эссе.

Answer (score 4):

- Дэвид Флэнаган. Java в примерах
- Hardcore Java. Robert Simmons
- Thinking in Java она же Философия Java  =)
- Патрик Ноутон.Герберт Шилдт. Java 2

А чтоб сразу с красивых аппликов

- SWT: A Developer's Notebook .Tim Hatton

Answer (score 4):

Авторы: Хорстманн К. С., Корнелл Г.

- Java 2. Том 1. Основы
- Java 2. Том 2. Тонкости программирования

Answer (score 4):

лучший способ научиться программировать - начать программировать

поиск, покупка книжек/ки - лишь способ оттянуть неизбежное, скачайте любую книжку для начинающих ("азы ...", " ... для чайников" и тп) в электронном виде (как вариант - найти отдельную статью на просторах), откройте первую главу и начните читать, на третей-10й странице будет пример простейшей программы типа "Hello world", ну и далее еще несколько примеров с простейшей арифметикой и операторами

возможно что книжка в ваших руках, именно то что нужно

поиск путей, исследование существующей подготовки, выслушивание советов, все равно (невзирая на результаты) рано или поздно приведут к этому шагу - 1 глава и Hello world :)

Comment: И твёрже на этом пути. К желаемому результату - стать "программером от сохи".

Comment: к чему сарказм ? других вариантов нет, с молоком матери не передается к сожалению :) это как езда на велике, теория помогает только когда уже ездил, до этого момента она пустой звук и груз странных видений

Comment: Сарказм к тому, что необходимость базовых знаний отрицать "небеспечно". ("Способ оттянуть неизбежное"). Ну а насчёт хелловорлда - ссылочка забавная: http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html (Перепевы на тему "эволюции программиста")

Answer (score 3):

> > > Сейчас хочу разобраться в основах программирования

Судя по оформлению вопроса, дело не в языках программирования. Учиться программировать надо начинать с изучения Computer Science.

- [Дональд Кнут, Искусство программирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- [Томас Кормен, Чарльз Лейзерсон, Рональд Ривест, Клиффорд Штайн Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ Introduction To Algorithms](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/)
- [Альфред В. Ахо, Джон Э. Хопкрофт, Джеффри Д. Ульман
  Структуры данных и алгоритмы](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4788523/)

И так далее

Comment: что-то я не заметил, что есть принятый ответ

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю что Pascal хорошо подходит для изучения азов программирования и понимания алгоритмов. 
Современные языки программирования во многом отталкивались именно от паскаля.
На своем опыте скажу, что после него я без труда начал осваивать с++ и РНР. 
Уверен многие со мной не согласятся, но это лично моё мнение.

Comment: Я соглашусь лишь с первой половиной утверждения, но не со второй. C и Pascal появились примерно в одно и то же время и не оказывали друг на друга влияния, поэтому они достаточно сильно различаются. Тем не менее, для обучения он действительно хорош и алгоритмы даёт изучить (в самом паскале библиотека настолько бедная (даже в дельфях), что всё писать приходится самому).

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, каждый из предыдущих авторов в чем-то прав.
Однако, я бы предложил Вам начать изучать программирование не с Java а с языка C(как подмножества C++) или Pascal (IMHO лучше даже с C/C++).

Аргументирую:

1. Простота и отсутствие не нужных на первых порах нагрузок (сторонникам Java - сплошные классы... Какое уж тут обучение основам если нужно каждую функцию оборачивать в класс?
2. Простой и интуитивно понятный синтаксис.
3. Наличие огромного количества учебников, в том числе на русском, в свободном доступе (Интернет).
4. Возможность продолжать изучение (структурное программирование, ООП) перейдя C->C++ или Pascal->Delphi.

Ну, собственно, можно еще продолжать, но особого значения не имеет. В дальнейшем будет еще проще - освоите один язык - другие будут даваться легче...

Если СОВСЕМ не знакомы с программированием и тяжело с английскими командами (типа if, then, else, while...), можете немного поиграть с ГЛАГОЛом (Русский язык программирование, поищите в гугл) - только немного, потому как это не стандарт...

Comment: про Java - гм, я слегка загнул про "каждую функцию", каюсь... Но все они, так или иначе - методы классов...

Answer (score 2):

**Си** самый лучший для начала. Язык маленький. Из сложностей - только указатели. (Правда, как говорит препод наш - "Никогда не думайте, что понимаете указатели до конца"). 
Насчёт того, что изучать с Кнута и Кормена...ух, ну это странный совет. 
Из книг по Си советую Стивена Прата ну и первоисточник - Брайан Керниган и Деннис Ритчи. 
Самый лучший учебник это гугл :)

Answer (score 0):

Ребят тут дело в том что человек Java хочет, а не азы программирования. С первой точки зрения Паскаль и Java - обсолютно разные языки (Java я б сказал даже технология).
Со второй точки зрения - да, паскаль дает представление не только о жутиках объектно-ориентированного программирования, но и структурного, модульного, так что для изучения азов - Паскаль пригоден и прост, для изучения Java технологии - никаким боком =)

Comment: Ну и где же вы жутики в ООП видели? :)

Comment: Это мое повседневное выражение, если оно вас смутило =)
А для новичка в ООП познакомиться со всем набором деструкторов/конструкторов,рекурсий,инкапсуляций,интерфейсов,коллекций и ОБЪЕКТОВ - думаю будет по-началу жутиками =Ь

Comment: согласен - еще ему надо объяснить про сборку мусора, наследование и т.д. - человек пишет что не Java хочет а хочет разобраться в основах программирования. Просто у него ЕСТЬ УЧЕБНИК по Java, Вот и все преимущества Java

Comment: Ну жутиков-то в ООП более чем достаточно. А ежели ещё добавить design pattern'ов от реинкарнаций убиенных руководителей КПК - Китайской коммунистической партии (книга "банды четырёх") - то ваащще.

Answer (score 0):

Опишите, какое у вас на данный момент образование - или по крайней мере, насколько вы знакомы с прикладной математикой - комбинаторикой, теорией графов, аналитом и.т.д.
Почему вы решили заниматься программированием, что именно больше всего интересует - web-программирование, 3d графика?
В любом случае я бы посоветовал начать с С++ (имхо, лучший учебник для начинающего - Стивен Прата)

Comment: Спорный совет. Да мейнстрим, "язык хлебный", но для старта лучше что-нибудь другое. Сложноват.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю для того чтобы начать изучать программирование необходимо выполнить следующие пункты:

1. Выбрать язык программирования; выбирается он исходя из предметной области, которая тебе интересна как будущему программисту: веб, прикладные программы и т.д. Есть узконаправленные языки, а есть общего назначения, так называемые универсальные, у каждого есть свои плюсы и свои минусы. Выбирать ассемблер для того чтобы написать свою CMS, а php для написания драйверов(такое даже невозможно наверно) по моему неразумно.
2. Язык всего лишь средство для достижения результата, помимо изучения самого языка, его синтаксиса, особенностей  и т.д. необходимо параллельно изучать базовые парадигмы программирования - принципы, подходы, алгоритмы, структуры данных и т.д., это поможет широко смотреть на вещи и применять эффективные, легкие и элегантные решения.
3. Усидчивость, терпение и систематичный подход к изучению приправленные энтузиазмом и желанием несомненно помогут тебе достичь успеха в освоении этой столь интересной профессии.

Comment: "Научитесь программировать за десять лет" (http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html) - перевод эссе Норвига с www.norvig.com  Весьма рекомендуется.

Answer (score 0):

Прально говорят - начинай c простейшего примера Hello World.
Изучение любого языка начинается именно так.
Но язык языком, а еще надо знать базы данных, алгоритмы, всякие протоколы...
Вот в институте этому всему учат.

Люди, советующие начать изучение с Pascal или Си, судя по всему, ностальгируют по этим языкам, потому что они сами с них начинали (сам такой, начинал с бейсика правда, потом уже паскаль и си.).

Но, советую начать с интерпретируемого языка (Java, .Net, PHP, Python и т.п.). Это избавит от проблем с выделением памяти и выходом за пределы массива. Эти вещи порождают весьма коварные, сложно исправляемые ошибки. А это, думаю, ни к чему. Хотя, конечно на ошибках учатся.

Java по сути интерпретируемый язык, но его все же нужно компилить сперва в объектный код. А уже этот объектный код интерпретируется.

Сам программлю на PHP, считаю этот язык самым простым, ну и просто привык уже. Не буду нахваливать, а то закидают какашками любители чего "посерьезней". Но мне нравится, почле массы всяких языков в институте, остановился на PHP и вполне меня устраивает.

Answer (score 0):

Начни отсюда: http://javarush.ru/user/reference/876d2f07-0ecc-419c-84fd-fd31616f2581 - хорошие задания и немного теории

и отсюда: 
https://www.youtube.com/user/KharkovITCourses - много теории.

Используя вместе, можно быстро выучить Java.

Comment: Начни от сюда

@DmitryPro обратите внимание - вопрос задан больше трёх лет назад, на него дано 13 ответов. Автор либо уже давным-давно начал, либо отказался от этой затеи.