# Книги по Java начинающему

Tags: java, книги

Книги по Java начинающему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобные вопросы уже задавались и даже точно такой же.

Вот, например, здесь вопрос был: [С чего начать изучение программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183/) и я же на него и отвечал. Здесь ответ такой же.

Answer (score 0):

"Философия java" - приятная книжечка.

Answer (score 0):

Смотреть в сторону книг издательства O'Reilly.

Answer (score 0):

Я начинал с книги [Java 2. Наиболее полное руководство](http://wmate.ru/ebooks/book24.html). Уж не знаю, насколько она хороша с точки зрения заядлых Java программистов, но меня вполне устроила как учебник для новичка. Правда Java не был для меня первым ЯП.