# Книги по Java 1.6

Tags: java, книги

Помогите подобрать книгу по Java 1.6 для новичка.

Answer (score 2):

- Спецификация Java(желательно на англ., но могу кинуть на русском)
- Эккель - Философия Java
- Хорстманн Кей, Корнелл Гари - Java 2. Библиотека профессионала. 7-е издание. Том 1 - Основы
- Хорстманн Кей, Корнелл Гари - Java 2. Библиотека профессионала. 7-е издание. Том 2 - Тонкости программирования (Читать после прочтения других книг)

  Кроме книг(не все же время их читать) можно попробовать обучаться:
- на видеоуроках, например [уроки Мирончика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/answers/32740/edit/)
- с использованием игры для обучения программированию(в том числе языку Java) -  Robocode
- непосредственным участием в opensource проектах(ИМХО лучший способ обучения, но будет много говнокода, так что в норм команду новичка не возьмут)

Answer (score 0):

Тут: "[С чего начать изучение программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183/%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)"