# С чего начать изучение программирования

Tags: java, python, книги

Давно хотела начать изучать программирование. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь книги, пособия и видео. Читала, что сначала нужно выучить язык программирования. Так ли это?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С чего начать изучение программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183/%d0%a1-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: А для чего вы хотите выучить язык программирования? Чтобы работать разработчиком, или вы видите какую-то другую сферу применения?

Comment: Задавайте такие вопросы в чате, а не сайте. Это оффтопик

Answer (score 1):

Начать изучать программирование надо с того, что-бы научиться самостоятельно Гууглить ответы ХОТЯ-БЫ на самые элементарные вопросы. Тем более, что ответов на них в сети - выше крыши. Без этого - ну никак. И книг, и видеокурсов, и статеек всяких -  и для школьников младших классов, и для взрослых дяденек (тетенек), желающих в 40 лет изменить сферу своей деятельности  (мы же не знаем, кто скрывается за скромным девичьим ником) -  в том числе. И на этом форуме - кстати, тоже.

Просто интересно, что лично вам помешало самой набрать такой запрос и прочитать ответ? Тем более, что вы уже "давно"(!!!) хотели начать. Вот только точно знаю, что программирование не любит ленивых и не самостоятельных.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте начать с вопроса "какой язык программирования учить?", понять какие виды программистов вообще бывают, как профессии,  https://tproger.ru/blogs/what-language-to-learn/ и поискать подобные статьи. Понять в какую сферу вам хотелось бы пойти (это веб, мобильные приложения, программы для корпоративных задач, итп). Далее определившись с сферой, надо понять какой язык стоит учить. Язык это инструмент разработки, навык программирования распространяется на все языки. После того как поймете какой язык программирования больше симпатизирует на основе прочитанных статей, отзывов и прочего - поищите курсы на ютубе, топ книг для новичка по этому языку итп. Вообще умение искать информацию - полезный навык :)